# RSS caching removes items from feed

Tags: rss, feed

I am pulling in a feed I know that has two items. When I add caching to craft.feeds.getFeedItems(feedurl, limit, cache) the first items is not pulled in.  However if I remove caching or add "0" that item is pulled in. Would this have something to do with the feed or craft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd parameter passed into [getFeedItems](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/FeedsService#getFeedItems-detail) is for an offset, not caching.  The caching parameter is in the 4th place and accepts any valid [PHP time format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php).